# Как проще сливать базы данных с одинаковой структурой

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть много баз данных с одинаковой структурой. Мне надо их слить в одну. Проблема в том что при сливе могут дублироваться id-шники (они же уникальные только в пределах одной базы) в одинаковых таблицах. И их нельзя просто заново сгенерировать insert-ом потому что на них есть ссылки из других таблиц... И таких ссылок много. Я уже замучился их мержить. Слить то не проблема union-ом, но вот с id-шниками очень сложно. Может для такой штуки уже придумано какое-то решение простое? Может я чего не знаю?

Comment: Можно написать какой-нибудь скрипт на каком-нибудь питоне, который будет генерировать новые айдишники и генерировать insert'ы с правильно поставленными новыми айдишниками

Comment: @andreymal я же сказал - проблема в ссылках. Мало просто сгенерировать id-шники. Надо еще ссылки обновить. А это не так просто.

Comment: Ну так тем же скриптом и перегенерировать ссылки)

Comment: думаю если в схеме нет чего-то необычного (вроде циклических зависимостей по данным) и таблиц немного (≤10, скажем), то можно залить данные во временные таблички/БД и одним-двумя запросами  чистого sql'я перебрасывать их... если придумаешь mcve'шку с данными могу подумать над конкретикой...

Comment: @Fat-Zer <=10? Серьезно? :D Нет, данных десятки тысяч строк в каждой таблице. Остальное не понял...

Comment: @DarkByte, таблиц≤10, а данных сколько угодно...

Comment: @Fat-Zer аа, мне показалось речь о данных. Невнимательно прочитал. Таблиц тоже прилично: около 20 штук.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У нас подобное было. Правда мы использовали Oracle.

Так вот чтобы сохранить уникальность в разрезе БД-источника мы делали доп. поле - ID БД грубо говоря(SOURCEID). И primary делали составной(из поля ID и SOURCEID)

**P.S:** Также можно использовать "смещение", чтобы не добавлять отдельное поле.

К примеру 
  `ID = 1, SOURCEID = 1;` будующий `ID = 100001;` И т.д.

Comment: Да, я уже тоже так пытался сделать. Но в итоге то мне от этого поля надо избавиться, а это не так просто... Т.е. его можно использовать при переносе, но зачем оно мне в проекте?

Comment: Сливка будет единовразовая? Вы можете тогда вначале слить все в одну БД, а потом пересчитать ID с учётом SOURCEID. К примеру ID = 1, SOURCEID = 1; будующий ID = 100001; И потом удалить, собственно, поле SOURCEID

Comment: Ну, возможно не совсем... Там просто раньше проект вместе с базой раз в год копировали. И сейчас пока не закончится текущий проект (он не на весь год, уже подходит к концу) нельзя последнюю базу копировать. Потом ее еще влить и все.

Comment: Кроме того еще одна проблема в том что могут дублироваться зарегистрированные юзеры (по email), а их уже надо выбрать уникальных только (сортирую по дате создания), а остальные не нужны.

Comment: тогда не меняя(не пересчитывая ID заново) будет проблематично. Только брать, вычитывать, и генерировать новый ID. И так каждую БД. Сделайте только какой-то флаг-поле, что запись перенесена в новую БД

Comment: Вобщем вас только спасет хитро написанный на каком-либо языке скрипт/программма миграции, где придется учесть пересчет, связи и прочие доп. условия(по аналогии с юзерами). Мы писали такие скрипты на PLSQL

Comment: Нда, короче простого решения нету. А это все я и так знал. Ну ладно. Буду дальше мучиться.

Comment: К сожалению. Найдете способ автоматизировать - напишите как ответ пож.

Comment: Слушайте, а сейчас подумал - и правда наверное отличным вариантом будет прибавлять к id таблицы id базы!!! Я то думал про id базы отдельным полем - это было бы сложно... А если прибавить просто то и правда может проканать! Буду пробовать!

Comment: ))) Вот и хорошо. Учтите только запас ID. К примеру миллион. Добавлю в ответ

Comment: А вот и не выйдет... Где гарантия что в итоге (уже после прибавления) не выйдет дубликатов? Например в одной базе с dbid = 1 были идентификаторы: 1, 2, 3, а в другой с dbid = 2: 2, 3, 4. После слива выйдет такой ряд: 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6. Видите? 4 повторяется два раза...

Comment: ну так учитывайте смещение. У вас в итоге получится с db1 = 1 ID будут 100001,100002,10003. А с db2 = 2 ID будут 200002,200003,200004

Comment: А зачем столько нулей? Вы уверены что при этом не будет дубликатов? Я не особо...

Comment: Это и есть вариант смещения. Дубликаты могут быть в любом случае, если вы достигните этого огромного числа. По-нормальному - надо пересчитывать ID заново. Но если не хочется - то можно заложится на вот такое огромное число. Костыль это, так сказать

Comment: Но так вероятность дубликатов ниже? Мне не то чтобы не хочется его пересчитывать - мне просто надо сохранить ссылочную целостность. А это не так то просто сделать если заново генерировать id. Ну ладно попробую сделать как вы сказали...

Comment: Чем больше число заложите - тем меньше вероятность. Главное с генерацией новых ID продумать

Comment: А что там продумывать? Если (будем надеяться) не останется дубликатов то id будет генерироваться для новых записей как обычно инкрементом от наибольшего. А для старых так и остается как перенесу.

Answer (score 2):

В качестве возможного решения.

Анализируем схему, берём на "карандаш" все связи, выявляем "кусты" (когда одно и то же значение соответствует более чем в 2 полях) и группируем. Для каждой связи подбираем такое значение `delta`, прибавление которого к `id` снимает проблему потенциального дублирования (ну то есть `delta > MAX(main_db.table.field)-MIN(add_db.table.field)` по каждой таблице, после чего берётся максимальная `delta` для всего куста связей).

Затем делается выгрузка данных из таблиц дополнительной БД в plain text с корректировкой ID-ов (как уников, так и рефералов) запросом типа

```
SELECT id + @delta1, field1, field2, ..., ref_field + @delta2, ...
INTO OUTFILE 'backup_tableX_filename' export_parameters
FROM add_db.tableX;
```

А загрузка выполняется уже без корректировки

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'backup_tableX_filename' import_parameters
INTO TABLE main_db.tableX;
```

Comment: хорошая идея, только вот OP в коментах к соседнему ответу пишет, что есть конфликты по другим UNIQUE-ограничениям, которые, как я понял, надо то ли игнорировать, то ли upsert'ом обрабатывать... есть идеи, что с ними сделать?

Comment: *есть конфликты по другим UNIQUE-ограничениям* Как я понял, там не проблема UNIQUE, а именно проблема дублирования. В этом случае слияние двух дубликатов - это отдельная операция, не очень сложная. А вот если там действительно UNIQUE CONSTRAINT - то это полная задница... И путь гораздо длиннее (втрое где-то). Выгружаем описанным способом во вторую таблицу, на основе первой и второй составляем третью таблицу, соответствия, имеющую доп. поля (Id1-Id2-min_Id) и без ограничений уникальности, после чего перебрасываем привязки, и затем возвращаем либо ограничения, либо данные в основную.

Comment: а если подумать, то можно просто дропнуть UNIQUE, обновить всё, удалить дубликаты, а затем добавить обратно...

Comment: Ну если база не боевая, а сеансовая - то можно и так.

Answer (score 1):

Просто не будет никак. У вас при проектировании никто видимо не представлял, что понадобится этот сценарий с множественными копиями и их слиянием, иначе бы задумались о какой-никакой соломке, например guid в качестве ключей или сегментации id.

Переводите потихоньку все базы с int на guid - будет проще слить воедино.
Этот вариант может оказаться более выигрышным в случае если объединение будет не единоразовым.

Также мне кажется исходя из комментариев, что вам скоро может понадобится инструмент merge записей. Я например, считаю подобные вещи вообще must have в информационных системах. Например, у меня объединить дубль клиентов в системе - дело нескольких кликов (больше всего времени уходит на указание какой клиент будет 'primary' (основным, куда вливаются данные), при этом корректно объединятся контакты (тоже с дубликатами!), заказы и т.п.

В этом плане возможно вам покажется интересными статьи на хабре про dadata.ru - парни пишут толковые технические вещи про дедупликацию бизнес-данных. Ну вот например, нашлось сходу в поиске: [DaData.ru находит и уничтожает одинаковых людей](https://habr.com/company/hflabs/blog/273251/)

Тут видите в чём фишка. Перестаньте думать о вашей задаче, как о "только SQL-запросами обойтись", не факт что получится.

Comment: Какие преимущества у guid перед обычным числовым идентификатором? Что-то я совсем не понимаю. Да и работать с guid все наверняка будет медленнее (int vs string => всегда число выигрывает в скорости перед строкой). А то что тут спроектировано гавено я и так знаю. Структура тут ужасная. Я ведь ее еще и нормализую заодно. Часть таблиц и столбцов - лишние или пустые, названия транслитом, битые ссылки (ссылающиеся на несуществующие записи) и тому подобные "прелести" на каждом шагу. Аццкая работенка :D